# Pairing mutual values based on different column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the next Data Set

```
      NAME   FRIEND
     --------------
     John    Ella
     John    Ben
     Ella    John
     Ella    Ben
     Dave    Ben
     ...
     More Values
```

I want to get a list of the mutual friends of John, Ella and Dave.
In this example the output should be `['Ben']`.

I've tried achieving this with `loc` but I wouldn't get the expected output, and would get 'friend's that aren't mutual.
`['Ella', 'Ben', 'John', 'Ben']`

Have searched for an answer for some time, couldn't find one that I might be duplicating.

Comment: Have you tried `groupby`, `merge` or `join`?

Comment: Couldn't see how it'll help me, (I'm not working with two tables atm, I don't want to group by since I need the different values in `FRIEND`)

Comment: You only have 1 table described here. Are we talking about two tables with each having half of the data, both are ("NAME", "FRIEND")?

Comment: There's only one table here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
ct = pd.crosstab(df['NAME'], df['FRIEND'])

out = ct.columns[ct.all()].to_list()
```

Or with set operations:

```
s = df.groupby('FRIEND')['NAME'].agg(set)
out = s.index[s.eq(set(df['NAME']))].to_list()
```

Output: `['Ben']`

Intermediate crosstab:

```
FRIEND  Ben  Ella  John
NAME                   
Dave      1     0     0
Ella      1     0     1
John      1     1     0
```

Intermediate `s`:

```
FRIEND
Ben     {Ella, Dave, John}
Ella                {John}
John                {Ella}
Name: NAME, dtype: object
```

##### if you want to specifically match `{'Ella', 'Dave', 'John'}`, even if the are other names in NAME:

```
target = ['Ella', 'Dave', 'John']

ct = pd.crosstab(df['NAME'], df['FRIEND'])

out = ct.columns[ct.reindex(target).all()].to_list()
```

Or;

```
target = {'Ella', 'Dave', 'John'}
s = df[df['NAME'].isin(target)].groupby(df['FRIEND'])['NAME'].agg(set)
out = s.index[s.eq(target)].to_list()
```

Comment: But there are three conditions here that aren't met, `'NAME'` should equal  `'John', 'Ella', 'Dave'`

Comment: @study.isLove it is met. Do you want to only match.those 3 names even if there were more in "NAME"?

Comment: Yes, I've seen the second version. Thanks can't upvote yet!

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example (no `...`), ideally as DataFrame constructor.